# Confusion about creating Cayley table for ($\mathbb{Z}_{18}^*,\times)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, cayley-table

On a test I ran into a question about a Cayley table.
The question was "Given the group $(\mathbb{Z}_{18}^*,\times)$, construct the Cayley table."
It also said that this group is sometimes referred to as $(U(18),\cdot)$.

What exactly is the set $\mathbb{Z}_{18}^*$? Because the Wikipedia says it's used as a set of non-zero integers, or non-negative integers. But I've also seen it used as a set of all primes up to 18?

And if I were to create a Cayley table using all primes up to 18, would the following table be the correct result?

\begin{array}{|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|}
\hline
×  & 1  & 5  & 7   & 11  & 13  & 17  \\ \hline
1  & 1  & 5  & 7   & 11  & 13  & 17  \\ \hline
5  & 5  & 25 & 35  & 55  & 65  & 85  \\ \hline
7  & 7  & 35 & 49  & 77  & 91  & 119 \\ \hline
11 & 11 & 55 & 77  & 121 & 143 & 187 \\ \hline
13 & 13 & 65 & 91  & 143 & 169 & 221 \\ \hline
17 & 17 & 85 & 119 & 187 & 221 & 289 \\ \hline
\end{array}

I realize this is a very basic question, but finding consistent information through Googling has not been fruitful for me.

Comment: Wikipedia does not say it is the set of nonzero/nonnegative integers. Nor have you seen it used as the set of all primes up to $18$. Its elements may be *represented* with integers between $1$ and $18$ which are relatively prime to $18$, but that's not the same as prime in general. Look up [modular arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic).

Comment: What exactly is the set $\mathbb{Z}_{18}^*$? Why don't you look up some examples for the definition? See [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplicative_group_of_integers_modulo_n), where  they have examples!

Comment: You didn't take the primes but the *relatively primes* to $18$, which is correct. You should take only the *remainders* of the products modulo $18$ in your table. You can also notice that $11\,13,\,17$ are congruent to, hence interchangeable with $-7,\,-5,\,-1$, respectively.

Comment: I have voted to reopen the question. It seems to me that the OP is confused, and has been trying (they have the essentially correct Cayley table, for example). We are here, after all, to help confused people who are trying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You listed the 6 *relatively primes* to $18$, and not the primes, which is correct.

Your Cayley table is also (somewhat) correct, but note that we are working in $\Bbb Z_{18}$, i.e. modulo $18$. That is, you should rather put the *remainders* of the calculated products modulo $18$.
For example, the last term is $17^2 =289\equiv 1\pmod{18}$ (because $288$ is even and its digits sum to $18$ which is divisible by $9$).

(By the way, if you keep on adding the digits in the numbers in your table until you reach 1 digit, then if the result is odd, it's just the remainder, if it's even, subtract $9$.)

But that's also a consequence of $17\equiv -1\pmod{18}$ (meaning that their difference is divisible by $18$), and that congruent numbers are *interchangeable* in modular arithmetic, just like equal numbers are so in normal arithmetic (i.e. one has e.g. $a\equiv b\pmod m\implies ac\equiv bc\pmod m$ and thus if also $c\equiv d$, then $ac\equiv bc\equiv bd$.)

So, here is a simplified version of the *same* Cayley table you wrote, but using smallest absolute value representatives:
$$\matrix{\times \\
& 1&5&7&-7&-5&-1\\ 
& 5&7&-1&1&-7&-5\\
& 7&-1&-5&5&1&-7\\
& -7&1&5&-5&-1&7\\
& -5&-7&1&-1&7&5\\
& -1&-5&-7&7&5&1}$$
You can also observe that $5$ generates this group: keeping multiplying by $5$ we receive the following cycle containing all group elements:
$$1\,\mapsto\, 5\,\mapsto \, 7\,\mapsto \, -1\,\mapsto \, -5\,\mapsto \, -7\,\mapsto \, 1\,\mapsto \, \dots $$

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you are using a convention which is just strangely unfamiliar to me, but I do not think that $\mathbb{Z}_{18}^*$ is meant to indicate the set of all primes up to 18.

For what I know, $\mathbb{Z}_n$ is mostly used as a short for $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$, which means the set of integers modulo $n$.
For example $(\mathbb{Z}_4,+) := (\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z},+) = \{0,1,2,3\}$ for the integer with addition.
The star is usually used to indicate the substructure of *units*, that is the group of those elements which admit inverses.
For example the set $(\mathbb{Z}_4,\times) := (\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z},\times)$ does not have an inverse for each element (which is the reason why it is not a group, besides the fact that the operation is not even closed). Take a look at the element $\bar{3}$. Then you got
$$
1\cdot 3 \equiv 3 \mod 4 \\
2\cdot 3 \equiv 2 \mod 4 \\
3\cdot 3 \equiv 3 \mod 4
$$
but you will not find an $x \in \mathbb{Z}_4$ such that
$$
x\cdot 3 \equiv 1 \mod 4 \; .
$$
The Cayley table is just a way to encapture the structure of a finite group in a nice tabular way. The Cayley table for $(\mathbb{Z}_3,+)$ would for example be 
$$
\begin{array}{|l|l|l|}
\hline
+  & 0  & 1  & 2  \\ \hline
0  & 0  & 1  & 2  \\ \hline
1  & 1  & 2  & 0  \\ \hline
2  & 2  & 0  & 1  \\ \hline
\end{array}
$$

Comment: Hey, $3\cong -1\pmod 4$ and $3\cdot 3=9\cong 1\pmod 4$. Nevertheless, $2$ is a zero divisor, so can't have multiplicative inverse.